# ARIMA unusual forecasts

Tags: python, arima

I am trying to implement the ARIMA model using statsmodels. I get really unusual results for my predictions, and was hoping for advice on fixing this.

```
arima = tsa.ARIMA(train[endogenous], exog=train.drop(endogenous,axis=1), order=(2,2,0),freq='B')
results = arima.fit()
prediction = results.predict(start=1,end=len(x)-1,exog=x.drop(endogenous,axis=1))
```

My actual dataset is this

```
2012-01-05    659.010
2012-01-06    650.020
2012-01-09    622.940
...
2013-11-08    1016.03
2013-11-11    1010.59
2013-11-12    1011.78
2013-11-13    1032.47
```

Prediction gives me this

```
2012-01-05   -10.551134
2012-01-06    -8.937889
2012-01-09   -27.941221
...
2013-11-08    14.739148
2013-11-11    22.567270
2013-11-12     1.844993
2013-11-13   -42.794671
```

It's unusual how even on examples that I trained on, the predictions aren't even in the same ballpark. When running on order (0,0,1), I got something closer

```
2011-06-01    525.632183
2011-06-02    528.051265
2011-06-03    523.168162
...
2013-11-08     609.294394
2013-11-11     613.877047
2013-11-12     607.953117
2013-11-13    1033.130417
```

In this case, the prediction did really well on the samples that it was trained on, but horribly on the test set.

EDIT: I tried looping through a bunch of different orders but it had negligible impact on the end result. I re-ran my model on order (1,1,2). Here were the coefficients:

```
const                              6.083430e+00
A                                  4.890720e-03
B                                  1.484685e-01
C                                  2.370248e-04
D                                  4.267728e-01
E                                 -4.398669e-08
F                                  5.203415e-01
G                                  5.349448e-03
H                                  2.198789e-03
I                                 -1.088271e-03
J                                 -3.295103e-03
K                                 -8.486572e-03
L                                  2.227050e-03
M                                 -1.844672e-02
N                                  1.561562e-04
O                                  8.622248e-03
P                                  1.560905e-05
Q                                 -1.705549e-02
R                                 -8.615488e-04
S                                  4.247976e-03
T                                  2.029798e-02
ma.L1.ENDOGENOUS                   1.088268e-01
```

Here was a summary:

```
                              ARMA Model Results                              
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:             ENDOGENOUS   No. Observations:                  449
Model:                     ARMA(0, 1)   Log Likelihood                 130.352
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              0.181
Date:                Thu, 28 Nov 2013   AIC                           -214.705
Time:                        10:18:46   BIC                           -120.243
Sample:                    06-01-2011   HQIC                          -177.470
                         - 02-18-2013                                         
===================================================================================================
                                      coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                               6.0834        nan        nan      0.000           nan       nan
A                                   0.0049      0.005      0.931      0.352        -0.005     0.015
B                                   0.1485      0.030      4.902      0.000         0.089     0.208
C                                   0.0002   8.36e-05      2.834      0.005      7.31e-05     0.000 
D                                   0.4268      0.002    216.200      0.000         0.423     0.431
E                              -4.399e-08        nan        nan      0.000           nan       nan
F                                   0.5203      0.001    356.889      0.000         0.517     0.523
G                                   0.0053      0.003      1.773      0.077        -0.001     0.011
H                                   0.0022      0.002      1.318      0.188        -0.001     0.005
I                                  -0.0011      0.000     -2.421      0.016        -0.002    -0.000
J                                  -0.0033      0.002     -1.937      0.053        -0.007  3.95e-05
K                                  -0.0085      0.002     -4.968      0.000        -0.012    -0.005
L                                   0.0022      0.001      3.398      0.001         0.001     0.004
M                                  -0.0184      0.003     -5.684      0.000        -0.025    -0.012
N                                   0.0002        nan        nan      0.000           nan       nan
O                                   0.0086      0.000     28.311      0.000         0.008     0.009
P                                1.561e-05        nan        nan      0.000           nan       nan
Q                                  -0.0171      0.001    -16.801      0.000        -0.019    -0.015
R                                  -0.0009      0.001     -0.900      0.369        -0.003     0.001
S                                   0.0042      0.007      0.570      0.569        -0.010     0.019
T                                   0.0203      0.013      1.621      0.106        -0.004     0.045
ma.L1.ENDOGENOUS                    0.1088      0.048      2.284      0.023         0.015     0.202
                                    Roots                                    
=============================================================================
                 Real           Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MA.1           -9.1889           +0.0000j            9.1889            0.5000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am not well versed in statsmodels, could you write down mathematical definition of your model? I.e what ARIMA model are you fitting and what are your exogenous variables? Also what are the fitted model coefficients?

Comment: See the middle of the site for the mathematical definition: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html. Please let me know if there is any other information I could provide. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are these constants, A, B, C, etc?

Comment: I am trying to forecast stock prices. The A, B, C's are different features like EBITDA, PE ratio, etc.